# Drag window with NSImage as handle?

Tags: xcode, macos, window, handle

I am writing a mac app and have used this code to hide the window handle,

```
[self.window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```

Well this is great, but i still need a handle to move around the window, so is there a way to move around the window from another object like an NSImage, acting like the window handle?

The code for my image is in the .h,

```
@interface WOWAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
        NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet NSImageView* winView;

}
```

and in the .m file,

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    NSString *inFilePathwin = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"win.png"];
    NSImage *winImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:inFilePathwin] autorelease];
    [winView setImage:winImage];

}
```

So the image is working and showing so how do i link that function?

Answer (score 4):

Hook the mouseDragged event on a NSView subview.

```
-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{       
CGFloat deltax = [theEvent deltaX];
CGFloat deltay = [theEvent deltaY];

NSRect frame = [[self window] frame];
frame.origin.x += deltax;
frame.origin.y -= deltay;

[[self window] setFrameOrigin:frame.origin];    
}
```

So

1. subclass NSView as XView
2. place your handle image in an instance of this view container.
3. Place the container where you want in the windows main view.
4. Use this snippet in XView to drag the window around.
5. Adjust the behaviour with the mouseDown and MouseUp events.

Comment: i'm new to app programing so how do i link everything?